# How to minimize/maximize a box with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How would I go about adding something to minimize this box I have and also maximise it once its been minimized?

Heres the code to display the box

```
<header class="info">
  <hgroup class="about">
    <h1><span class="online_users"> <span id="reload_users"  class="reload_users"></span> Online</span> | <span class="room_loaded"> <span   id="reload_rooms" class="reload_rooms"></span> Rooms</span></h1>
  </hgroup>
  <nav class="more">
    <a href="#buyvip">Buy VIP</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

and heres the css for it

```
    <style type="text/css">
      @-webkit-keyframes show-info {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
      }

      @-moz-keyframes show-info {
        0% { -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg); }
        100% { -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
      }

      @-ms-keyframes show-info {
        0% { -ms-transform: rotateY(120deg); }
        100% { -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
      }

      @-o-keyframes show-info {
        0% { -o-transform: rotateY(120deg); }
        100% { -o-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
      }

      @keyframes show-info {
        0% { transform: rotateY(120deg); }
        100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
      }

    .info {
      -webkit-transition: all 180ms ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 180ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 180ms ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 180ms ease-out;
      transition: all 180ms ease-out;

      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;

      -webkit-transform: perspective(800);
      -moz-transform: perspective(800);
      -ms-transform: perspective(800);
      -o-transform: perspective(800);
      transform: perspective(800);

      font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 12px;
      opacity: 0.65;
      color: #fff;
      z-index:9999;
      width: 240px;
      right: 210px;
      top: 0px;
      border: #333 solid 1px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .info:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      opacity: 1.0;
    }

    .info h1,
    .info h2,
    .info h3 {
      line-height: 1;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }

    .info .about, 
    .info .more {
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
      -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
      -o-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
      transform-origin: 0% 50%;

      -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(120deg);
      -o-transform: rotateY(120deg);
      transform: rotateY(120deg);

      margin-bottom: 1px;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
      padding: 12px 15px 12px 20px;
    }

    .info .about {
      -webkit-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 600ms 1 normal forwards;
      -moz-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 600ms 1 normal forwards;
      -ms-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 600ms 1 normal forwards;
      -o-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 600ms 1 normal forwards;
      animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 600ms 1 normal forwards;

      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .info .about h1 {
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 19px;
      opacity: 0.95;
    }

    .info .about h2 {
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 13px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .info .about h3 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-size: 11px;
    }

    .info .about h3:after {
      margin-left: 4px;
      font-size: 14px;
      content: '\203A';
    }

    .info .more {
      -webkit-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 500ms 1 normal forwards;
      -moz-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 500ms 1 normal forwards;
      -ms-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 500ms 1 normal forwards;
      -o-animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 500ms 1 normal forwards;
      animation: show-info 500ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) 500ms 1 normal forwards;

      padding: 5px 15px 10px 20px;
    }

    .info .more a {
      -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      transition: all 200ms ease-out;

      border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-right: 10px;
      font-size: 10px;
      opacity: 0.6;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .info .more a:hover {
      opacity: 0.99;
    }
  </style>
```

would anyone be kind enough as to help me achieve what I am trying to do?
It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can change CSS classes with javascript using `<HTMLElement>.classList.add(<string>)` and `<HTMLElement>.classList.remove(<string>)`. Try it yourself please!

Answer (score -1):

I have not read your styles, base on description:
You can make 2 classes, called -MIN and -MAX

Consider you have wrapped all boxes to a div with MAX style:
then you may have something like this:

```
<div class='my-prefix-MAX'>
     ...
     <button onload = "resize()">Minimaze<button>
     ...
<div>
```

JS:

```
function resize(){
   if(this.parrentNode.className.indexOf('MIN')>-1){
       this.parrentNode.className.replace('MIN','MAX');
       this.value = 'Maximize'
   }else{
       this.parrentNode.className.replace('MAX','MIN');
       this.value = 'Maximize'
   }
}
```